# How to check UIButton tag is set or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have need an action if it has any tag value for a UIButton.

If it has no tag value need to take another action.

I have tried following but it is crashing.

```
-(void)buttonClick:(id)sender {

    NSInteger t = [sender tag]; //crashing here if it has no tag value

    if(t) {
        //action
    } else {
        //another action
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the crash message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, u have to set button.tag=100

```
if ([sender isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

        // Then you can reference the title or a tag of the clicked button to do some further conditional logic if you want.
        if(btn.tag==100)
        {

         }
}
```

Comment: Why to set tag value to 100? Why not to do just "if([sender tag] == 0)". @Ramesh Kumar

Comment: its ur wish its not compulsion